# how to divide my dataset by the number of times a value appears in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset and need to know on average how many times the number 1 appears, the number 0 appears, and the number -1 appears. But it is not a traditional average. I explain:

this is part of my dataset:

```
position
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
-1
 0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
 1
 1
```

So if I subset the number of times each number appears by vectors I would have:

```
position '1'   position '-1'  position '0'
  X1  X2         X1  X2         X1  X2
  1   1          -1  -1          0   0
  1   1              -1          0
  1                  -1
                     -1
                     -1
```

This way I can find the average for 1 as: (X1+X2)/2 where 2 is the number of vectors that appear. This depends and can be any number given by the number of consecutive times a number appears.

This is a little confusing but I hope you understand my point. I have been thinking how to do this but can't find a way.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The function `rle` will get you very close to what you want, you just need to rearrange its output slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rle` is the way to go, as mentioned by @KonradRudolph.  Then you can use `split` to get a proper format

```
with(rle(position), split(lengths, values))
# $`-1`
# [1] 1 5
# 
# $`0`
# [1] 2 1
# 
# $`1`
# [1] 3 2
```

And, to do the averaging, `tapply` would work

```
with(rle(position), tapply(lengths, values, FUN=mean))
#  -1   0   1 
# 3.0 1.5 2.5
```

Comment: And if you like this method, but prefer `data.frame` to `array` output, you can use `aggregate` via `with(rle(position), aggregate(lengths ~ values, FUN = mean))`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `dplyr` with `diff`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(group = c(0, cumsum(diff(position)!=0))) %>% 
         group_by(position) %>%
         summarise(mean = n()/length(unique(group)))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  position  mean
     (int) (dbl)
1       -1   3.0
2        0   1.5
3        1   2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit verbose, but this shows how all of this comes together:

```
library(dplyr)
position <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1)
rle_pos <- rle(position)

df <- data_frame(position_code = rle_pos$values,
                 length = rle_pos$lengths)

df
# Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
# 
#   position_code length
#           (dbl)  (int)
# 1             1      3
# 2             0      2
# 3            -1      1
# 4             0      1
# 5            -1      5
# 6             1      2

df %>%
  group_by(position_code) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            sum_lengths = sum(length)) %>%
  mutate(average = sum_lengths / count)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# 
#   position_code count sum_lengths average
#           (dbl) (int)       (int)   (dbl)
# 1            -1     2           6     3.0
# 2             0     2           3     1.5
# 3             1     2           5     2.5
```